# Transformer Problem Diagnosis

Tags: transformer

I have a suspected bad transformer in a board that has come out of a treadmill which I'm trying to use for another project. I suspect the transformer as I have removed all connectors and replaced one by one until from the main switch back until the the RCD trips and it's when the transformer is connected that I start to get the problem, so this is my first point of investigation.

The transformer is set up like this: [image: 3 Winding Transformer]

The transformer has 2 connectors sharing 6 wires which I have identified as per the diagram on the transformer as 2 red (240v), 2 yellow (22v), 2 black (10v). 

I'm trying to confirm the transformer is the problem and have done the following:
Tested continuity across all combinations:

- Yellow wires have continuity with each other
- Black wires have continuity with each other
- Red wires have no continuity.
- No continuity on any other combinations (i.e. blacks to yellows to reds etc)

I've also measured the voltage coming out of each coloured wire pair when putting the transformer near another working transformer (technique I found on a youtube video) and had the following outputs which relative to the diagram seem fine.

- Red - 0.55v
- Yellow - 0.055v
- Black - 0.001v

Question 1 - given that yellow and black wire pairs have continuity, should the red wires have continuity too. It seems weird that winding would have a voltage when near another transformer if it doesn't have continuity.

Question 2 - is there any other tests I can do to check if this transformer is the problem or if it's further into the circuit.

Comment: Can you check resistance instead of continuity? There will be more turns on the 220V side, so a higher resistance - depending on the threshold that your tester considers to be "continuous," there may or may not be a problem there. Also, you say that as soon as you connect the xformer, there's a problem - what problem? and how can you test the circuit without the xformer? Finally, if you connect the xformer to 220V, what outputs do you get?

Comment: whoa! don't just connect the transformer to 220v! If you have another transformer with a low voltage output, connect it to that, you will still see the same ratios. If not, put a low wattage filament lamp in series with the transformer when you test it, to limit any fault current.

Comment: Ground the frame! put a 1A fuse in one of the red wires connect it to 220 and see what it gives you.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that the red wires actually have no continuity if they are really the primary winding. If that was the case, the transformer would do nothing when connected to the mains circuit. If you are using a multimeter to check for continuity, it is trying to measure impedance and give you a value in ohms. I have found that cheaper multimeters seem to get confused by the high inductance of the primary circuit of small transformers. I have known-good transformers that read no continuity with my cheaper multimeters.

An alternate test for checking continuity is to wire the primary in series with a circuit that has a DC current. For example, a 5 VDC power supply, a 100 ohm resistor, and a cheap LED. If the LED lights, the circuit has continuity. The LED must connected in the correct direction to be forward biased. This is a cheap, effective circuit for checking DC continuity. The peak current is only 50 milliamperes, so it is unlikely to cause damage to the transformers winding. The LED will be a bit unhappy at this current level but will not die instantly.

If you have a transformer that is tripping an RCD (also called as a GFCI), there are a few possibilities

1. You have connected it wrong. The circuit theoretically *can* work using the line and ground wires. This is unsafe however, this trips the RCD. It's also worth mentioning the outlet could be wired wrong. However, in that case anything plugged into that outlet should trip it.
2. The transformer is shorted to its metal case. If the transformer has its 220 volt primary shorted to its metal case (even with a very high impedance) it is allowing current to flow from the line to the ground. This trips the RCD. This is very dangerous if it is true. You can test for this by placing the transformer on a very good insulator, like a sheet of plastic. If you have a kitchen cutting board that is plastic and white in color, that could be used. If it does not trip the RCD when placed on an insulator, it is likely that it is shorted in someway. Do not touch the transformer whatsoever while performing this test.
3. You have an RCD *that is also an arc fault detector*. Some RCD breakers have a circuit to detect the energy from an electrical arc and trip. It is possible that due to poor manufacture or lightning damage, there is a tiny arc in the primary of the transformer. This is usually the result of several turns being shorted together by a carbon track from a lightning strike.

Comment: Thanks @eric I tested resistance instead of continuity on my multimeter and got 638ohm on red, 17.4 on yellow and 2.6 on black. I haven't had a good chance to look at it further but I might try some of your suggestions.